# Immutable.js and flatMap equivalent function

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, flatmap

Was just wondering if there an equivalent flatMap function in Immutable.js? I have been using this node package https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatmap for a while but I would prefer to write things like this

```
listObject.flatMap(x => ...)
```

Instead of

```
flatMap(listObject, x => ...)
```

Comment: what about [List#flatMap](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/flatMap) in Immutable.js?

Comment: If I could I would mark you comment as the correct answer.

Yep, for some reason I didn't find flatMap in the Immutable.js docs (not the easiest to use docs) but after looking again carefully I see the iterables have a flatMap function.

Comment: @foomip I updated my answer. However, I think it is a good idea to leave my old answer too, just for future users who are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a `flatMap` function (see [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/flatMap)).

However, if you ever face a similar problem (you want to use `foo.bar(args)` instead of `bar(foo, args)`) you can create a custom property of your instance.

```
listObject.flatMap = a => flatMap(listObject, a);
```

And after that it is equivalent to write `flatMap(listObject, x => ...)` and `listObject.flatMap(x => ...)`.